# Combine network geometry and topology in python

Tags: python, networking, triangulation

First I will describe the main thing I want to achieve. I have a spatial data-set (polygon shapefile) which I need to triangulate, create the dual graph of the 
triangulation and apply some algorithms like A* and depth first search on the dual graph.

I created the triangulation in a GIS software (FME) which I want to handle in python to get the dual graph and apply the above mentioned algorithms.

My question is how to maintain both the geometry and the topology of the triangulation in order to handle it with python. Here you can find a screenshot of part of my polygon triangulated [polygon_triangulation_image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OWtII.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured out a possible solution. I used the library [tri](https://pypi.org/project/tri/) which takes as input a shapefile and writes the triangulation output in a wkt file along with the adjacency information for each triangle. The data structure used for storing the adjacensy is the one specified by [CGAL](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/TDS_2/index.html#Chapter_2D_Triangulation_Data_Structure). The result of tri library works better than scipy Delaunay since it also take as constraints the polygons' edges. Tri currently works with Python 2.

Answer (score 0):

You could implement it in a [Quad edge datastrucutre](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/afs/andrew/scs/cs/15-463/2001/pub/src/a2/quadedge.html). This represents both the graph and its dual and also holds for every vertex it's position. But I'm actually not sure if there exists a package for this in python or if you need to implement it on your own.